# Scroll-up gesture on mobile shows browser bar first, and only further gesture actually scrolls page up

Tags: mobile, scroll, chakra-ui

I'm developing a web application with React, and I sometimes view it on a mobile web browser. This web browser automatically hides the address bar if I scroll down (to provide a full-page experience) and automatically shows it if I scroll up.

However, something unexpected happens when I scroll up.

Assume that I scroll down the web page for a while, then stop, and then attempt to scroll up. I notice a strange behavior: the first gesture to scroll up does not cause the page to scroll but rather just shows the address bar of my browser. Visiting other websites with the same browser shows a more normal behavior: scrolling up shows the address bar *and* and the same time scrolls the page up.

This is bad for my users because they have to scroll twice if they want to go up: once to show the address bar, and a second time to actually scroll up.

Why is the first scroll-up gesture not causing the page to scroll?

---

Notes:

- Sometimes this behavior also happens when the address bar is already visible. More specifically I think this happens if I scroll up, then wait, then scroll up again (when the last scroll starts the address is already visible, but the scroll doesn't have any effect).
- I set my browser to show the address bar at the bottom, but this behavior also happens when the address bar is at the top.
- I tried to write minimal code to reproduce this error, but the Next.JS dev server somehow gave me inconsistent results at my attempts to reproduce the error. However, below is a sketch of how a page of my web app looks.

```js
const MyPage: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <SomeContext.Provider value={someValue}>
      <MyLayout>
        <MyHeader />
        <MyBody />
      </MyLayout>
    </SomeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const MyBody: React.FC = () => {
  const [isLargerThan800] = useMediaQuery("(min-width: 800px)");
  return isLargerThan800 ? (
    <>
      {Array.from({ length: 1000 }).map((_, i) => (
        <p key={i}>Desktop content...</p>
      ))}
    </>
  ) : (
    <>
      {Array.from({ length: 1000 }).map((_, i) => (
        <p key={i + 1000}>Mobile content...</p>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

interface LayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <CookieBanner />
      <Box
        backgroundColor="monochrome.super-light-gray"
        backgroundImage="url('/cross_background.svg')"
        backgroundRepeat="repeat"
        backgroundAttachment="scroll"
      >
        {children}
        <Footer marginTop={12} />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

---

Here are the technologies I'm using:

- React 18.2.0
- Next.JS 13.4.8 (with the pages router)
- Chakra UI 2.7.1, including its `useMediaQuery` function
- Firefox mobile browser 115.0.1 (with address bar at the bottom)